# Initial Image bytes

Tags: windbg, masm32

If I debug an asm file with Windbg the image is loaded at a location in memory, in my case its 00400000. If I dump the data from 00400000 I can see my assembly code is loaded in the image file at and offset of 10000 from this address and not at 00400000.

Here's the dump for the start of the image.

```
00400000 ->  00905a4d 00000003 00000004 0000ffff
00400010 ->  000000b8 00000000 00000040 00000000
00400020 ->  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00400030 ->  00000000 00000000 00000000 000000c0
```

So, my question is what is this header at the start of the image and what is it used for? It looks like all images have this header.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's defined in **PE(portable executable) Image Format**. You can find its specification on Microsoft website.

Comment: tyvm I'll take a look.

Comment: Got it, thanks Peter. I did a quick check of that but the endianness caught me out.

Comment: Is this answered? Maybe you want to delete your question or self-answer it.

Comment: Yes Peters comment answered my question.

Comment: well if you self answer you may also try !dh 400000 windbg will decipher the header for you

Answer (score 1):

What you have posted looks like a PE header in 32 bit format:

```
0:000> dd 00400000 
00400000  00905a4d 00000003 00000004 0000ffff
00400010  000000b8 00000000 00000040 00000000
00400020  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00400030  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000080
```

If you dump it as bytes, it will show the ASCII characters along with it and you can easily recognize the "MZ" header.

```
0:000> db 00400000 
00400000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
00400010  b8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........@.......
00400020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00400030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  ................
```

You can use the `!dh` command to decode it:

```
0:000> !dh 00400000 

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
FILE HEADER VALUES
     14C machine (i386)
       3 number of sections
5911398E time date stamp Mon May  8 20:37:50 2017

       0 file pointer to symbol table
       0 number of symbols
      E0 size of optional header
      22 characteristics
            Executable
            App can handle >2gb addresses
[...]
```

If you don't want to use WinDbg, there's [Stud_PE](http://www.cgsoftlabs.ro/studpe.html) where you can load an executable and it will analyze it for you.